# Google Maps Api V3 how to create different marker icons (no xml used)

Tags: google-maps

We pull data from a mysql database to create a google map that contains around 150 markers. The script is rather old. Some years ago we opted for a non-xml solution. While this might not be perfect, it works pretty good. We have three types of locations and would like to use different marker icons for that. I'm not sure how to do that. Here is the script:

```
var icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/icons/mm_20_red.png",
new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
var center = null;
var title = "Für mehr Infos bitte klicken!";
var map = null;
var currentPopup;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function addMarker(lat, lng, info, type) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt,
        icon: icon,
        map: map,
        title: title
    });
    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: info
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        if (currentPopup != null) {
            currentPopup.close();
            currentPopup = null;
        }
        popup.open(map, marker);
        currentPopup = popup;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
        currentPopup = null;
    });
}

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.607685, 10.688126),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.LARGE
        }
    });

    <?
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM markers");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $vorname = $row['vorname'];
        $lat = $row['lat'];
        $lon = $row['lng'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $strasse = $row['strasse'];
        $plz = $row['plz'];
        $ort = $row['ort'];
        $telephone = $row['telephone'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $image = $row['image'];
        $type = $row['type'];
        if ($row['image'] != "") {
            echo("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<img style=\"float:left; margin: 0px 5px 0px 0px\" src=\"$image\" width=\"80\" height=\"80\" /><b>$name, $vorname ($type)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br/>$strasse<br/>$plz&nbsp;$ort<br/>$telephone<br/><a href=\"mailto:$email\">$email</a>');");
        } else
            echo("addMarker($lat, $lon,'<b>$name, $vorname ($type)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br/>$strasse<br/>$plz&nbsp;$ort<br/>$telephone<br/><a href=\"mailto:$email\">$email</a>');");
    } 
   ?>
}
```

So, we fetch all the data in the db and echo them. If there's an image, we show that in the popup. If not, we skip it. We have one additional column "type". We would like to use different markers for those type. Let's say a red one for type A, a blue one for type B, and a green one for type C. How could we do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the color of the icon based on the type and use the image of that color as the marker icon.

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, info, type) {
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    bounds.extend(pt);

//  Added code starts here
    var color = "black";
    if(type == "A")
    {
       color = "red";
    }
    else if(type == "B")
    {
       color = "blue";
    }
    else if(type == "C")
    {
       color = "green";
    }
    var imageicon  = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/" + color + ".png";
//  Added code ends here

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: pt,
        icon: imageicon, //replace icon with imageicon
        map: map,
        title: title
    });
    var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: info
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        if (currentPopup != null) {
            currentPopup.close();
            currentPopup = null;
        }
        popup.open(map, marker);
        currentPopup = popup;
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
        currentPopup = null;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. We are getting closer. The problem is, that the type is still unknown when we need it for the if-statement (the mysql query comes later). Since this is not xml-based, we probably have to put the marker icon to the addMarker() part (after the db query). Unfortunately, I can't find any information on how to do that.